# Error in vusial studio (E0869, could not set locale ".1252")

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors

info:
Visual studio 2019
Windows 10(russian locale)
project - any c++ project (projects on other languages works perfectly)

after creating any c++ project visual studio, wrote E0869 error on first string 
I could find 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/405876/e0869-could-not-set-locale-1252.html
They offer a few steps.
On step 'wrote "chcp 1252"' i got "invalid code page". (I guess it may be related with problem in visual studio)

Searching in search engines (Google\yandex) haven't results.
Did anybody meet and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After two hours of searching the solution came by accident:
compiler additional options "--locale=US"